# .NET SSH with certificate authentication

Tags: .net, ssh, sftp, openssh

I am looking for a way to authenticate to an OpenSSH SFTP server using an SSH certificate in .NET.

I can do this on the command line on linux or a newer version of Windows:

```
sftp -o CertificateFile=~/.ssh/sftpuser-cert.pub -i ~/.ssh/sftpuser sftpuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do the equivalent or I am misreading/misunderstanding docs from multiple vendors.  Can anyone post an example of how to do this?  Just to be specific I am NOT asking about authenticating with an SSH key in .NET, but with a certificate in "OpenSSH" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"certificates"* is a proprietary feature of OpenSSH. It's not a standard SSH thing. The standard SSH uses plain key files.

Support for OpenSSH certificates in other clients/libraries is rare.